# RPL children-list Contiki

Tags: c, contiki

I am trying to test whether or not the DIO messages in the file rpl-icmp6.c are coming from a child of the node that receives the DIO. Can anyone help me?

I have seen that contiki do not keep a list of the children, only the parents. Therefore, I am not sure how to do it?

Pseudocode:

```
if(senderOfDIO is child) {

   check the rank of the packet

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running RPL in storing mode, you can tell which nodes are directly connected by looking at the routes towards them and checking whether the nexthop of the route is the same as the endpoint addess.

This is an example of code that loops over direct children:

```
#include "ipv6/uip-ds6-route.h"

static void
iterate_children(void)
{
  uip_ds6_route_t *route;

  /* Loop over routing entries */
  route = uip_ds6_route_head();
  while(route != NULL) {
    const uip_ipaddr_t *address = &route->ipaddr;
    const uip_ipaddr_t *nexthop = uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route);
    if(uip_ipaddr_cmp(&address, &nexthop)) {
       /* direct child: do somehting */
    }

    route = uip_ds6_route_next(route);
  }
}
```

To solve your question specifically, use something like this:

```
static uint8_t
is_direct_child(uip_ipaddr_t *address)
{
  uip_ds6_route_t *route;

  route = uip_ds6_route_lookup(address);
  if(route != NULL) {
    const uip_ipaddr_t *nexthop = uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route);
    if(uip_ipaddr_cmp(&address, &nexthop)) {
       /* nexthop and the address are the same */
       return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Very good answer! A quick followup question: In the is_direct_child, should I send in the childs IP address or the hosts IP address?

Comment: the address `argument` is meant to be the IP address of the child.

Comment: I understand! So I call `is_direct_child` like this: `is_direct_child(&from)`, where from is received like this:   `uip_ipaddr_copy(&from, &UIP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);`. However, in the `uip_ds6_route_lookup(address)` can not find any routes at all. It outputs: `uip-ds6-route: Looking up route for fe80::c40c:0:0:3 `, then the next output is `No route found`. Can you think of any reasons why @kfx?

Comment: If i remember correctly, you will not not see link-local addresses in the routing tables. You need a proper, routable prefix, such as "fd00", and the route has to be already discovered by RPL for it to show up in parents routing table (DIO & DAO message exchange finished).

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about how `uip_ds6_route_lookup(address)` and `uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route);` works? Or where I can find some info about it? I have looked at the documentations, but struggle with what gets return. Also: Why do you compare the childs IP address with next hope? Should it not be the the parents IP address? @kfx

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if that was helpful.

Comment: As for the other questions, the comments in SO are not for extended discussions. Read the Contiki source code, it's really the best way to understand to learn about the system. And feel free to ask follow up questions, once you can make them fit the SO format.

Comment: @kfx After find children of a parent, how to say in some interval if mote's ID is equal a number, then disconnect from it? Is it possible to access to mote's ID in contiki?

Answer (score 0):

Either in RPL Storing mode or Non Storing Mode the DIO from a parent node to child node will be sent in two senarios.
1 Before forming a DODAG
2 Periodically sent DIO after the formation of the DODAG.

Every time the DIO will be multi casted except to respond to Child node send out DIS.

To test whether or not the child is receiving DIO message, can be seen in COOJA which is a virtual simulation.

In Non storing mode, all the nodes other than router will not store the child address. Here packet forwarding will be done by Source Routing Header (SRH) which carries all the address.